# How can i replace in Angular 6+ inside a <p-dataTable> and <p-column> tag a value with an icon?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, datatable

I have an array coming from the java backend to my Angular 6 frontend (using **p-dataTable** und **p-column** tag for displaying it) . 
  
The **names** of the fields of the Array are: '**0**', '**1**', '**2**'. 
Field '2' has 1 character, either ('**E**' or '**D**' - for enabled/disabled). 
**My question is:** 
Is it possible in my implementation (see below) to **replace** the '**E**' with a green check **icon** (fontawesome) and the 'F' with a red X **icon** (but i wanna use the p-dataTable and p-column tag)? 
**My code is:**

```
<p-dataTable *ngIf="!loading && hasEntries"
           [value]="list"
           [(selection)]="selectedRowData"
           (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
           [selectionMode]="selectionMode">

<p-column *ngFor="let col of columns"
          [field]="col.field"
          [header]="col.header"
          [sortable]="true">
</p-column>
```

**and the code of the icons I wanna replace with the characters ('E' and 'F') is:**

```
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**The definition of the columns:**

```
  this.columns = [
  {
    field: '10',
    header: this.translationService.getTranslation('...')
  },
  {
    field: '9',
    header: this.translationService.getTranslation('...')
  },
  {
    field: '11',
    header: this.translationService.getTranslation('...')
  },
  {
    field: '7',
    header: this.translationService.getTranslation('....')
  },
  {
    field: '5',
    header: this.translationService.getTranslation('....'),
  },
];
```

**And a picture of the structure of the incomming request:**
  [What is comming from the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfVnX.png)

Thank you very much for you helpful answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the template needed for the header and body at that case you have full control of how ou want to display the values

```js
<p-dataTable *ngIf="!loading && hasEntries"
           [value]="list"
           [(selection)]="selectedRowData"
           (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
           [selectionMode]="selectionMode">

  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
       <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
             <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === '2'; else other">
                     <i class="fa" 
                      [ngClass]="{'fa-check' : rowData[col.field] =='E' , 'fa-times :rowData[col.field] =='F'  ]}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <ng-template #other>
                   {{rowData[col.field]}}
              </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
        </td>
       </tr>
   </ng-template>       

<p-dataTable>
```

**Updated!!**

for primeng verion 4 there was an old component related to datatable called `p-dataTable`

```html
<p-dataTable *ngIf="!loading && hasEntries"
           [value]="list"
           [(selection)]="selectedRowData"
           (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
           [selectionMode]="selectionMode">

<p-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data="rowData">
        <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === '2'; else other">
            <i class="fa"
             [ngClass]="{'fa-check' : data[col.field] =='E' ,'fa-times' : data[col.field] =='F' }" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #other>
            {{data[col.field]}}
        </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>

<p-dataTable>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzba1y)

Comment: I'm using latest version of primeng

Comment: @JoeDashes I have update my answer for old version of primeng

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, but the version doesn't works for me again ... I got an empty array thats all ...

Comment: @JoeDashes what version of primeng are you using  ?

Comment: I am using the version 4.3.0

Comment: It seems like the App don't wanna see what is in the rowData[col.field]. in the second line [value] must be = reviewListe

Comment: Any other idea ?

Comment: there was a lot of typoes any way I have update the answer and include a demo work base of primeng 4

Comment: @JoeDashes check the demo  I have fix the icon problem  https://angular-kzba1y.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thank you very very much my friend. The solution worde perfectly. Thank you for yout time you spended my problem :). Have a very very nice day !!!!!!!!